# change sql permission to prevent SQL injection

Tags: sql, security, prepared-statement, sql-injection

I'm currently making a website using PHP and MYSQLi. And I've been read a lot about SQL injection. As answered on other questions from StackExchange, 2 ways of prevent it is by using prepared statement and escaping string. Since I'm not able to do prepared statement (I've tried to make it based on tutorials and videos but can't make it work) so I chose another way(escaping string). My question is, if I change permission for user at my SQL login page, to only able to do 'SELECT' query. Will it able to give me extra security measure to prevent user from DROP, ALTER, etc on my database. Because my website :-

1. Not require any user to register.
2. The only text field link to my query is for full text search function (which only use SELECT for the query and I have mysqli escape string on this text field).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always a good idea to give your application's database login only the permissions it needs.  If it doesn't need to do inserts or updates, don't give it insert or update permission.

However, attackers may still be able to exploit SQL injection vulnerabilities to read unauthorized data using select statements, so you still need to protect your queries against that.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you get it all wrong (which is no wonder, given all the tons of rubbish posted in Stack Overflow).

> prevent it by escaping string.

It doesn't prevent injections

> Will it able to give me extra security measure

No.

> I'm not able to do prepared statement

Consider hiring a programmer then. Think of your customers. And your business, after all. If you, say, want to be a bus driver, you have to *buy* a bus - not making it out of wood logs and clay, endangering your passengers. Exactly the same thing here - if you need a site to sell your goods - *buy* a site, instead of making it yourself

Comment: I only have 1 word. It's learning. I love learning new things. I want to learn as many fields as I can. It's not I can't afford to buy a site but I prefer to do it myself so I can know from A-Z about it. Not to bragging but currently I have 2 stores which give services of electrical, air-conditioning, piping, and internet cafe operated for more than 4 years even I know nothing about this fields at the start. Funny thing is, the way I'm treated when I learn those fields is same as the way you treated me when I try to learn PHP and MYSQL now.

Comment: You already declined learning, mind you, confirming that you abandon the most basic and essential tool. Yet there are things far more complex than prepared statements. Think twice if you really want to waste your time.

Comment: And as for my internet cafe software. It was made with Visual FoxPro by me and my old friend. I learn FoxPro also from zero but now if any bug found on new update, I believe I can solve it myself ^_^

Comment: Nope.. even until now I still try to do prepared statement. But first things come first so I believe it can be done later

Comment: Hello sir, this maybe from ages ago. But I'm finally fully understand ,able to make prepared statement and fully migrate all my code into prepared statement type. My web currently on testing stage by my friends for any bugs. In 2-3 months ahead, I plan to make another 2 webs and I'm interested to offer you to make 1 of the web (travel agency or electrical services). Once I collect enough materials, I will email it to you.